Why can't I get PySpark to drop the right duplicate columns after a 'leftouter' join with a Dataframe that is itself the result of a join?
I have the following input dataframes:
expected = spark.createDataFrame(
    # fmt: off
    data=[
        {"id": "1", "group": "1", "start": 1_000_000, "stop": 1_001_200, "info": "info1"},
        {"id": "1", "group": "6", "start": 6_001_000, "stop": 6_003_330, "info": "info2"},
        {"id": "1", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_100, "stop": 3_081_000, "info": "info3"},
        {"id": "2", "group": "1", "start": 1_000_000, "stop": 1_001_200, "info": "info4"},
        {"id": "2", "group": "6", "start": 6_001_000, "stop": 6_003_330, "info": "info5"},
        {"id": "2", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_100, "stop": 3_081_000, "info": "info6"},
    ],
    # fmt: on
    schema=StructType(
        [
            StructField("id", StringType(), False),
            StructField("group", StringType(), False),
            StructField("start", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("stop", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("info", StringType(), False),
        ]
    ),
)

found = spark.createDataFrame(
    # fmt: off
    data=[
        {"id": "1", "group": "1", "start": 1_000_000, "stop": 1_001_200},
        {"id": "1", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_103, "stop": 3_080_500},
        {"id": "1", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_511, "stop": 3_081_000},
        {"id": "2", "group": "1", "start": 1_000_005, "stop": 1_001_200},
        {"id": "2", "group": "6", "start": 6_000_000, "stop": 6_003_009},
        {"id": "2", "group": "6", "start": 6_003_015, "stop": 6_004_000},
        {"id": "2", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_100, "stop": 3_080_500},
        {"id": "2", "group": "9", "start": 3_080_496, "stop": 3_080_996},
    ],
    # fmt: on
    schema=StructType(
        [
            StructField("id", StringType(), False),
            StructField("group", StringType(), False),
            StructField("start", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("stop", IntegerType(), False),
        ]
    ),
)

If I do a 'leftouter' join of them with 'id' and 'group' and drop the duplicate columns used in the join from the right, I get the columns with null values dropped, as expected:
joined_left_outer_without_range = (
    expected.join(
        found,
        on=[
            expected.id == found.id,
            expected.group == found.group,
        ],
        how="leftouter",
    )
    .drop(found.id)
    .drop(found.group)
)

print("joined_left_outer_without_range:")
joined_left_outer_without_range.show()

joined_left_outer_without_range:
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+
| id|group|  start|   stop| info|  start|   stop|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|  1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|1000000|1001200|
|  1|    6|6001000|6003330|info2|   null|   null|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|3080511|3081000|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|3080103|3080500|
|  2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|1000005|1001200|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|6003015|6004000|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|6000000|6003009|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|3080496|3080996|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|3080100|3080500|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+

However, if I first join the columns with an 'inner' range join, and then try to join the results of that join with the original dataframe using a 'leftouter' join, attempting to drop the duplicate columns comming from the right dataframe, actually drops the columns from the left dataframe and leaves the null values from the right dataframe:
joined_range_overlap = (
    expected.hint("range_join", 300).join(
        found,
        on=[
            expected.id == found.id,
            expected.group == found.group,
            expected.start < found.stop,
            expected.stop > found.start,
        ],
        how="inner",
    )
    .drop(found.id)
    .drop(found.group)
    .withColumn("found_start", found.start)
    .withColumn("found_stop", found.stop)
    .drop(found.start)
    .drop(found.stop)
)

print("joined_range_overlap:")
joined_range_overlap.show()

joined_with_missing_overlap = (
    expected.join(
        joined_range_overlap,
        on=[
            expected.id == joined_range_overlap.id,
            expected.group == joined_range_overlap.group,
            expected.start == joined_range_overlap.start,
            expected.stop == joined_range_overlap.stop,
        ],
        how="leftouter",
    )
    .drop(joined_range_overlap.id)
    .drop(joined_range_overlap.group)
    .drop(joined_range_overlap.start)
    .drop(joined_range_overlap.stop)
)

print("joined_with_missing_overlap:")
joined_with_missing_overlap.show()

joined_range_overlap:
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
| id|group|  start|   stop| info|found_start|found_stop|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|    1000000|   1001200|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080103|   3080500|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080511|   3081000|
|  2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|    1000005|   1001200|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6000000|   6003009|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6003015|   6004000|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080100|   3080500|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080496|   3080996|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+

joined_with_missing_overlap:
+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
| info|  id|group|  start|   stop| info|found_start|found_stop|
+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
|info1|   1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|    1000000|   1001200|
|info2|null| null|   null|   null| null|       null|      null|
|info3|   1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080511|   3081000|
|info3|   1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080103|   3080500|
|info4|   2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|    1000005|   1001200|
|info5|   2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6003015|   6004000|
|info5|   2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6000000|   6003009|
|info6|   2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080496|   3080996|
|info6|   2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080100|   3080500|
+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+

Why is this not working as expected, and how do I get PySpark to drop the intended columns without explicitly renaming the columns?
Note: the reason I am doing these as two separate joins is that I am trying to use the Databricks range join optimization hint, which is only performed for 'inner' range overlap join.

I believe this is happening because after left outer joining expected and joined_range_overlap, you have duplicate column names, and pyspark is not dropping the ones you intend. You can see the full table below:
joined_with_missing_overlap = (
    expected.join(
        joined_range_overlap,
        on=[
            expected.id == joined_range_overlap.id,
            expected.group == joined_range_overlap.group,
            expected.start == joined_range_overlap.start,
            expected.stop == joined_range_overlap.stop,
        ],
        how="leftouter",
    )
)

+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
| id|group|  start|   stop| info|  id|group|  start|   stop| info|found_start|found_stop|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|   1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|    1000000|   1001200|
|  1|    6|6001000|6003330|info2|NULL| NULL|   NULL|   NULL| NULL|       NULL|      NULL|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|   1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080511|   3081000|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|   1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|    3080103|   3080500|
|  2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|   2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|    1000005|   1001200|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|   2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6003015|   6004000|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|   2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|    6000000|   6003009|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|   2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080496|   3080996|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|   2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|    3080100|   3080500|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----------+----------+

You can use table aliases to make it work as intended:
expected = expected.alias("e")
joined_range_overlap = joined_range_overlap.alias("j")

joined_with_missing_overlap = (
    expected.join(
        joined_range_overlap,
        on=[
            expected.id == joined_range_overlap.id,
            expected.group == joined_range_overlap.group,
            expected.start == joined_range_overlap.start,
            expected.stop == joined_range_overlap.stop,
        ],
        how="leftouter",
    )
    .drop(F.col('j.id'))
    .drop(F.col('j.group'))
    .drop(F.col('j.start'))
    .drop(F.col('j.stop'))
)

joined_with_missing_overlap:
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
| id|group|  start|   stop| info| info|found_start|found_stop|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1|    1|1000000|1001200|info1|info1|    1000000|   1001200|
|  1|    6|6001000|6003330|info2| NULL|       NULL|      NULL|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|info3|    3080511|   3081000|
|  1|    9|3080100|3081000|info3|info3|    3080103|   3080500|
|  2|    1|1000000|1001200|info4|info4|    1000005|   1001200|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|info5|    6003015|   6004000|
|  2|    6|6001000|6003330|info5|info5|    6000000|   6003009|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|info6|    3080496|   3080996|
|  2|    9|3080100|3081000|info6|info6|    3080100|   3080500|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+


Yeah, I wound up going with aliases; but I still don't understand why spark can't figure out which column to drop when I explicitly refer to the column in object attribute syntax. I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the columns in joined originated from expected and still have some kind of reference to that dataframe when I join with it again, but I'm just guessing.
